# Remove quote marks from a list in python

Tags: python, list

I have a [list in txt file](https://www.docdroid.net/ghbZBNQ/liz-txt) and I want to remove the quotation marks from the numbers.
For example the list:

```
['1023', '1025', '1028']
```

change to

```
[1023, 1025, 1028]
```

How do I do it in Python?

Comment: Convert the contents to `int`?

Comment: If you have the list as text and just want to hard-code the replacement, use a tool like Notepad++ and use its replace feature.

Answer (score 2):

We can use a list comprehension here along with `int()` to convert each string in the list to an integer.

```py
inp = ["1023", "1025", "1028"]
output = [int(x) for x in inp]
print(output)  # [1023, 1025, 1028]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
lst  = ['1023', '1025', '1028']
list(map(int, lst))
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is probably:

Your list:

```
a = ['1023','1025','1028']
```

And change it to a NumPy array:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array(a).astype(float)

Out: array([1023., 1025., 1028.])
```

Or `astype(int)` depending on if you want items after the decimal point.

```
Out: array([1023, 1025, 1028])
```

Comment: Installing third-part libraries to do something this trivial is overkill. And it changes the output format in a different way to boot.

Comment: Well just about everyone with Python has NumPy and it makes it easier to do any math operations if needed.  I have no idea what this person is doing with the numbers.